# How can I make columns and rows incrementable in a grid from the ViewModel and Xaml?

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm, gridview

I am new to Xamarin and I have a problem making a two column listing. It only shows them in a single column. What I am trying to do is add a binding on the Grid.Column so that the variable would be increased and it would do it automatically.

```
"Xaml"
  <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
        <Label Text="Mis Cupones" FontSize="Title" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"></Label>
        <ListView x:Name="EventListView"
              Margin="0,8,0,0"
              HasUnevenRows="True"
              SeparatorVisibility="None"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid Padding="4" Margin="4">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width=".5*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width=".5*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                            <cards:SfCardView CornerRadius="30,30,30,30"  Padding="5" BackgroundColor="#E88A1A"  Grid.Row="{Binding Row}" Grid.Column="{Binding Column}">

                                <Grid  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill"  >
                                        <Label 
                                       FontAttributes="Italic"
                                       FontSize="27"
                                       MaxLines="1"
                                       HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                       Text="{Binding Nombre}"
                                       TextColor="#e0eeeb"
                                        />
                                        </StackLayout>
                                        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" Padding="0,45,0,0">

                                            <ff:CachedImage x:Name="ImgCupones" Source="{Binding Url}" LoadingPlaceholder = "icon_usuario.png" WidthRequest = "90" HeightRequest = "90" CacheDuration = "30" RetryCount = "5" RetryDelay = "450" DownsampleToViewSize = "true" Aspect="AspectFill" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Start" >
                                                <!--<ff:CachedImage.Transformations>
                                                    <ffTransformation:CircleTransformation />
                                                </ff:CachedImage.Transformations>-->
                                            </ff:CachedImage>
                                            
                                </StackLayout>

                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="0,110,0,0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"> 
                                        <Label 
                                       FontAttributes="Italic"
                                     
                                       FontSize="14"
                                       HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                       Text="{Binding Descuento}"
                                       TextColor="#50d6a3"
                                        />

                                        <Label 
                                       FontAttributes="Italic"
                                       FontSize="16"
                                      
                                       HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                       Text="%Descuento"
                                       TextColor="#e0eeeb"
                                        />
                               
                                    
                                        
                                    </StackLayout>
                                    <StackLayout  Padding="0,170,0,0" >
                                        <Button Text="Detalle" WidthRequest="5" HeightRequest="35"></Button>
                                    </StackLayout>
                             
                                
                            </Grid>

                        </cards:SfCardView>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
```

"ViewModel"

```
class CuponesPageViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    ApiService apiServices = new ApiService();
    public string idUsuario { get; set; }

    public int _column;
    public int Column
    {
        get => _column;
        set => SetProperty(ref _column, value);
    }

    public int _row ;
    public int Row
    {
        get => _row;
        set => SetProperty(ref _row, value);
    }





    public ObservableCollection<CuponModel> Items { get; }

    public CuponesPageViewModel()
    {
        Column = 0;
        Row = 0;
        RegistroModel Usuario = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RegistroModel>(Application.Current.Properties["jsonInicio"].ToString());
        idUsuario = $"{Usuario.idUsuario}";
        string response = "";

        try
        {

            Task.Run(async () =>
            {

                response = await apiServices.Cupones(idUsuario);

            }).Wait();

            List<CuponModel> consulta = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CuponModel>>(response);
            //SfCardView cardView;
            Items = new ObservableCollection<CuponModel>();
            foreach (CuponModel consultas in consulta)
            {
                Items.Add(consultas);
                if (Column <= 1)
                {
                    if (Column == 1)
                    {
                        Column = 0;
                        Row++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Column++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: use CollectionView - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/layout#horizontal-grid

Comment: I agree with the suggestion to use CollectionView instead of Grid. Nevertheless, I'll point out what would need to change. First, this question: given that Column and Row are properties of `CuponesPageViewModel`, how will the Binding know which Column and Row *each* item has? Answer: it won't know. Add Column and Row as properties of `CuponModel`. Then as you adjust page's Column and Row, you also copy those to the current item: `consultas.Column = Column; consultas.Row = Row;`. (There is a more elaborate technique where you create a `CuponModelView` class, but that is more complex.)